# TF14045: The identity Build Agent is not a recognized identity

Tags: tfs, build-process

We have TFS 2013 build agents. We recently upgraded from 2012. Every time I run a build I get this error.

> **Exception Message: TF14045: The identity Build Agent is not a recognized identity. (type IdentityNotFoundException)**
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository5.CheckIn(String workspaceName, String ownerName, String[] serverItems, Changeset info, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, Int32 checkinOptions, Failure[]& conflicts, Failure[]& failures, Boolean deferCheckIn, Int32 checkInTicket, Int32 maxClientPathLength)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.CheckIn(String workspaceName, String ownerName, String[] serverItems, Changeset info, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, Int32 checkinOptions, UploadedBaselinesCollection uploadedBaselinesCollection, Failure[]& conflicts, Failure[]& failures, Boolean deferCheckIn, Int32 checkInTicket)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PagedCheckin(IEnumerable`1 changes, Boolean changesIsAllPendingChanges, Changeset changeset, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, CheckInOptions2 checkinOptions, UploadedBaselinesCollection uploadedBaselinesCollection, Failure[]& conflictsArray, Failure[]& failuresArray)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckInInternal(WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters, Int32 operationId)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn(WorkspaceCheckInParameters checkinParameters)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: TF14045: The identity Build Agent is not a recognized identity. (type SoapException)SoapException **Details: <detail IdentityName="Build Agent" />**
>   Exception Stack Trace:

Most issues similar to this seem to include a guid in place of the identity. In our case it looks like a default value of "Build Agent" is present. I've done a lot of searching and cannot figure out where this value is persisted.

<detail IdentityName="Build Agent" />

I've deleted and recreated the build agents with no success. Here is what the build agent configuration looks like.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how we can update the identity to reflect the service account we configured?

Comment: Can you create a clean build based on the *.12.xanl template and see if that executes?